# Execute different function based on data in Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, promise

Execute different function in Promise.all

Hi I'm new to javascript. I need to fetch data from different server which are dependent on each other. I want to execute different function depending on promise.

let us suppose I have fetched user data:

```
 let p1 = SomeApi.fetchUser();
 on successfull I want to execute function A


 let p2 = SomeApi.fetchStudent()
 on successfull I want to execute function B

let p3 = SomeApi.fetchSomething()
on successfull I want to execute function C

 How to achieve some thing like this

 Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(data => {
  if(p1) {
    A()
  }
  if (p2){
    B()
  }
  if (p3) {
    C()
  }
 })
```

Assume all data are dependent on each other .

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `if it's p1`. `Promise.all` waits for *all* Promises to resolve, not just one of them, it's not `Promise.race`. Sounds like you just need `.then`, not `Promise.all`?

Comment: So you want `Promise.all([p1.then(A), p2.then(B), p3.then(C)])`? Or `.then(data => A(data[0]); B(data[1]); C(data[2]); })`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to call `.then` on the existing Promises. If you need a *different* action to take place once all Promises have resolved, then use `Promise.all`:

```
let p1 = SomeApi.fetchUser();
p1.then(a);
let p2 = SomeApi.fetchStudent()
p2.then(b);
let p3 = SomeApi.fetchSomething()
p3.then(c);

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(data => {
  // all Promises have resolved
})
```

If `a`, `b`, and `c` are completely synchronous and aren't expensive, you have them return the resolve value, and define each outer Promise to the chained call:

```
let p1 = SomeApi.fetchUser()
  .then(a);
let p2 = SomeApi.fetchStudent()
  .then(b);
let p3 = SomeApi.fetchSomething()
  .then(c);

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(data => {
  // all Promises have resolved
})
```

where `a`, `b`, and `c` are something like:

```
const a = (aData) => {
  // do something with aData
  return aData;
};
```

Returning the data at the end of the individual callback allows the `Promise.all` to use the resolve values from *all* Promises (if that's needed).

If there may be errors, then of course you should handle them as well with `catch`, eg:

```
let p1 = SomeApi.fetchUser();
p1.then(a).catch(handleErrors);
let p2 = SomeApi.fetchStudent()
p2.then(b).catch(handleErrors);
let p3 = SomeApi.fetchSomething()
p3.then(c).catch(handleErrors);

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(data => {
  // all Promises have resolved
}).catch(handleErrors)
```

Comment: In the first snippet, errors from `a`, `b` and `c` are not handled – I would recommend to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

You can add .then function to handler for dependent.

```
let p1 = SomeApi.fetchUser().then(()=>{
A();
return Promise.resolve()
});
 //on successfull I want to execute function A


 let p2 = SomeApi.fetchStudent().then(()=>{
B();
return Promise.resolve()
});
 //on successfull I want to execute function B

let p3 = SomeApi.fetchSomething().then(()=>{
C();
return Promise.resolve()
});
//on successfull I want to execute function C

 How to achieve some thing like this

 Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(data => {
  if(data[0]) {

  }
  if (data[1]){

  }
  if (data[2]) {

  }
 });
```